# Formulario para editar usuario PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Actualmente tengo un formulario para editar un usuario, el cual mediante un método GET obtengo los datos de la base de datos para poder realizar el update, sin embargo hay 2 campos que no me los esta arrastrando correctamente

este es el codigo que tengo al inicio del archivo asi como el Get y Update

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'conexion.php';
    
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    
    
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $tipo_usuario = $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'];
    
    if($tipo_usuario == 1){
        $where = "";
        } else if($tipo_usuario == 2){
        $where = "WHERE id=$id";
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios $where";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

    
    if  (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=$id";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          $usuario = $row['usuario'];
          $nombre = $row['nombre'];
          $tipo_usuario = $row['tipo_usuario'];
        }
      }

      if (isset($_POST['update_user'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $usuario= $_POST['usuario'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $tipo_usuario = $_POST['tipo_usuario'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
      
        $query = "UPDATE usuarios set usuario = '$usuario', nombre = '$nombre', tipo_usuario = '$tipo_usuario', password = SHA('$password') WHERE id=$id";
        mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Task Updated Successfully';
        $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'warning';
        header('Location: tabla.php');
      }


    
?>
```

Cuando elijo este por ejemplo para editar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me captura el usuario y password pero no el nombre ni el tipo de usuario, en el nombre me captura siempre el de la sesion iniciada (la contraseña esta encriptada por eso sale asi)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo del formulario es este

```
<form action="editar_usuario.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="POST">
                                
                                            

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuario</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario"  class="form-control" required="required" value="<?php echo $usuario; ?>" >
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" >
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>" >
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo de Usuario</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <select name="tipo_usuario"  class="form-control" >
                                            <option <?php if($tipo_usuario==1){echo "selected";} ?> value="1">Administrador</option>
<option <?php if($tipo_usuario==2){echo "selected";} ?> value="2">Analistas 1</option>
<option <?php if($tipo_usuario==3){echo "selected";} ?> value="3">Analistas 2</option>
                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                                    
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4">
                                            <input type="submit" name="update_user" Value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            
                                                                                    </form>
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar en que esta fallando el codigo o donde esta el error

Comment: Hola marco, nos puedes explicar exactamente en que necesitas ayuda?

Comment: No se entiende en qué parte del código ocurre el problema exactamente. Quizá sea bueno que expliques brevemenre cómo tienes organizado el código.

Comment: El inconveniente es que cuando le quiero dar editar a un usuario, en el formulario que aparece, los campos Usuario y Password si los captura bien de la base de datos, pero el nombre y tipo de usuario no, ese es el problema

Comment: Revisa como se llama el campo nombre en el `<td></td>` desde donde se lanza la acción de edición. En tu código publicado no se ve esa parte.

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama el archivo del 1er bloque de código en la pregunta? Otra cosa, ¿por qué si el método del formulario es `POST` usas la super global `$_GET` para recoger los datos? Aunque a veces funciona (por suerte) lo correcto es siempre usar la superglobal del método que definiste en el formulario... La cosa es más incoherente todavía, porque pasas también datos por URL. Cambia el método del form a `GET` (así se enviará todo por URL dando coherencia). Luego, para depurar, coloca un `var_dump($_GET);` en el archivo PHP donde estarías recibiendo los datos del formulario y dinos qué muestra.